# Integrating OpenID into iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, openid

I want to make my application run when the user enters OpenID credentials.

How can I integrate that to my application?

I have already used Janrain's free version and because it only supports a limited number of users, I need a different option.I want Open source.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using the Janrain framework that can be found here:
http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/mobile

**Note** the sidebar on the right that explains how iPhone developers can easily integrate this into there apps

Also, Janrain supports more than just OpenId which is a plus. It supports 20+ social networks including:

Aol, Yahoo!, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google, MySpace, Windows Live, PayPal, Salesforce.com, foursquare, Hyves, Verisign, MyOpenID, OpenID, Flickr, Blogger, Livejournal, Wordpress, Orkut, VZ-Netzwerke and Netlog.

Comment: i want open source/free API for this

Comment: You should specify these things how else will answerers know